# iterative GA optimization algorithm

Tags: arrays, matlab, genetic-algorithm, optim

The following code creates a cosecant squared radiation pattern. There is a phases and amplitude_norm_V vector which are the coefficients of AF expression. I am looking to create a GA iterative algorithm that given a known AF data will recreate phases and amplitude coefficients. I was given a link to a possible method shown below.
How to implement it in matlab?
Thanks.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter#:%7E:text=Least%20mean%20squares%20(LMS)%20algorithms,desired%20and%20the%20actual%20signal

[image]

i wrote the matlab code

```
    amplitude_norm_V=[0.3213,0.4336,0.7539,1,0.7817,0.3201,0.32,0.3261];

    x=sqrt(1/(sum(amplitude_norm_V.^2)));
    real_voltage=amplitude_norm_V.*x;
    real_power=(real_voltage.^2);
    sum(real_power);
    phases=[129.9121,175.4215,-144.6394,-116.9071,-93.7603,-60.0165,55.2841,89.4477]
    norm_phases=phases-175.4215;
    theta=linspace(0,pi,1000);
    theta_0=pi*(135.315/180);
    f=5.6;

    N=10;

    lambda=300/f;
    k=(2*pi)/lambda;
    d=0.8*lambda;
    total=0;
    tot=0;
    for z=1:8
    total=total+AF;
    tot=tot+AF.^2;
    end
    plot((theta/pi)*180,20*log10(total));
```